# process identification with Modelica models and PID controller design

Tags: modelica, dymola, pid-controller

I try to build a PID controller for a valve in my model, I plan to do some process identification, get the system response to a step pulse and the transfer function of the system, then I could design the PID controller. But I am not sure if there is a Modelica library for this kind of job, or I need to do this manually.
My question is :
Is there any good reference examples for me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in the Dymola manual to tune a controller of an airplane. It is found in the design library, more precisely: `Design.Optimization.Examples.ControllerDesign_F14`. The documentation is found in the Dymola Manual 2, Chapter 3 up to Dymola 2020x.

Another option is the commercial library "Optimization" developed by DLR which has enhanced capabilities, but comes with some cost...

Comment: Could these libraries output the transfer functions of a system? I'd like to do system identification and get the describing function of a subsystem.

Comment: I think not. You should be able to use the (free) linearSystems2 library to create a transfer function...

Answer (score 2):

What you need to perform a step response is a controller which can be put in 'manual' mode. The free library https://github.com/mbonvini/IndustrialControlSystems gives you that.

Comment: Could I get the transfer function based on the response with this library? I didn't find the option to output the transfer function. I wanna get the transfer function use it to analyze how to design controllers.